# ebay ReviceItem - Item description passing HTML (versus plain text)

Tags: ebay-api

I've read the API documentation but can't work out what I need to set correctly, if wanting to send the item "description" in html format (vs plain text), this is from the API

"The seller's description of the item. In listing requests, you can submit your description using CDATA if you want to use HTML or XML-reserved characters in the description"

....so by 'enveloping item description HTML with 'CDATA' .... is all the ebay receiving server needs to know that the data beign sent is HTML  (i thought there'd be an API attribute I'd need to set to specify that the data I'm sending is HTML?